# Neo4j: Why are paths of length 0 not returned?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Imagine a simple scenario where a Company has Products, and this data:

```
(c:Company {name: 'Uber'})-[:has_product]->(p:Product {name: 'Uber App'})
```

I would expect this query

```
match (c:Company)-[:has_product*0..1]->(p:Product)
return c.name, p.name;
```

to return

```
Uber, null
Uber, Uber App
```

since the path can be of length 0. However, it returns only

```
Uber, Uber App
```

Am I misunderstanding how paths work in Neo4j?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing how the zero length match works.  The zero length relationship hop will match the start node itself. In your query though the end node in the path specifies the `:Product` label. Since the first node has the `:Company` label your query will never yield a zero length match.  If you try the following query without the label specified on the end node you should return a few rows: one where *'Uber'* is in both columns and the other where *'Uber'* is in one column and the other column had the product *'Uber App'*.

```
MATCH (c:Company {name: 'Uber'})-[*0..1]->(p)
RETURN c.name, p.name;
```